# Should one say "Asher Yatzar" when giving a urine sample?

Tags: halacha, medicine, asher-yatzar

Should one say "Asher Yatzar" when giving a urine sample? This is assuming that the sample is "forced" and not when the person normally goes to the bathroom. He is urinating specifically for the purpose of the sample, not for ridding waste.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23215

Comment: He should definitely not say it when giving the sample. Perhaps when he is done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See *Minchas Yitzchak* (6:38:3) that after producing a urine sample, the bracha of *Asher Yatzar* is said. It does not matter that it was induced and not completely natural.

See *Mishnas Avraham, Orach Chayim* 7 fn 8 that Rav SZ Auerback agrees with *Minchas Yitzchak* but cites an otherwise difficult and possibly dissenting view of *Chavos Yair*.